# Rails ActiveRecord conditional validations for associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have the following code with a "save as draft" feature that should prevent validations from running (i.e. they should only run when the status is not draft). I'm not sure how to pick up on this in my associated models, to keep them from being validated:

```
class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_one :primary_presenter, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title,               presence: true
  validates :primary_presenter,   presence: true, unless: :draft?
  validates :abstract,            presence: true, unless: :draft?
  validates :description,         presence: true, unless: :draft?

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :primary_presenter

  def draft?
    status.draft?
  end
end


class Presenter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :proposal

  validates :email,           presence: true, unless: :proposal_is_draft?
  validates :first_name,      presence: true, unless: :proposal_is_draft?
  validates :last_name,       presence: true, unless: :proposal_is_draft?
  validates :title,           presence: true, unless: :proposal_is_draft?

  def proposal_is_draft?
    proposal.status.draft?
  end
end

class PrimaryPresenter < Presenter
end
```

Of course the problem is that presenter.proposal is nil when the record hasn't been saved yet. I've looked into reject_if: :all_blank for the nested attributes, but that doesn't seem to do quite what I want since I still want the record to be created even if it is blank, so that when editing later the record will exists. Also I want to allow partial submissions if saving as draft. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is sufficient, but one possibility is to accept that when proposal is nil, proposal_is_draft? is effectively true. In that case, you could redefine it to:

```
def proposal_is_draft?
  !proposal.persisted? || proposal.draft?
end
```

Though this looks doesn't look great, it would return true when the proposal is not persisted, and return true when the proposal is a draft (changed from status.draft to use the method you defined in Proposal class).

Answer (score 0):

I never really use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, personally, but you might try "rolling your own" validation for the association rather than using the standard model validations, if you're happy to use `reject_if` on the parent model instead of validating the child model directly.

```
class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :primary_presenter, dependent: destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :primary_presenter,
    reject_if: primary_presenter_invalid?

  def primary_presenter_invalid?(attributes)
    return false if draft?
    [:email, :first_name, :last_name, :title].each do |attr|
      return true if attributes[attr].blank?
    end
    false
  end

end
```

Then I guess remove the validations on the `Presenter` model. Though it seems like you might still want those, if you ever create or update presenters in any way other than via nested attributes on proposals?